# Import enquire breaks all Javascript

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I'm trying to use enquire to have separate scripts for mobile. When I import the module, all JS stops working in chrome. No errors reported.
I am new to modules, I think there's something I don't know about using node modules in the browser.

```
import enquire from "enquire.js";
```

HTML

```
    <script type='module' src='./scripts.js' ></script>
```

eslint:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

EDIT: I see that when I include the import statement my JS file disappears from Sources in chrome

Comment: The error would occur in your build process, not in the browser.

Comment: I'm not following, could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you run an NPM script to compile scripts.js? That's where the fault probably lies.

Comment: I don't, I can't find docs on this, do you  have a link? If the script is listed in my package.json it should work right?

Comment: I think I need to use webpack